# Is it logical to find difference between same question, same people yes/no answers but different time?

Tags: group-differences

I have 22 patients with certain symptom (have(yes)/don't have(no)) before and after treatment. Is it logical to find difference between having or not having the same symptom after treatment? For example: 18 had a symptom and after treatment just 4 have that symptom. So is there a statistically significant difference between those?
Thank you in advance.